# performance of running select queries in parallel

Tags: oracle

(note this isnt about parallel execution of a query inside the RDB, but peformance characteristics of submitting queries in parallel).

I have a process that executes 1000's (if not 10,000s+) of queries, in a single threaded manner (i.e. send, wait for response, process, send....), loosely of the form

```
select a,b from table where id = 123
```

i.e. query a single record on an already indexed field

on an oracle database.

This process takes longer than desired, and doing some metrics on it, I'm sure that 90% of the time is spent server side execution (and transport) rather than client side.

This process naturally can be split into N 'jobs', and its been suggested that this could/should speed up the process.

Naively you would expect it to run N times quicker (with a small overhead to merge the answer).

Given that (loosely) SQL is 'serialised' is this the case though? That would imply that actually it would probably not run quicker at all.

I assume that for an update on a single record (for example) N updates would have to be effectively serialised, but for N reads, this may not be the case.

Which theory is most accurate (or neither)

---

I'm not a dba, it looks like for reads, reads never block reads, so assuming infinite resources the theory would be that N reads could be run completely in parallel with no blocking. For writes and reads it gets more complex depending on how you set up your transactions/locks but thats out of scope for me.

Comment: Maybe. Without any numbers this is impossible to answer

Comment: what sort of numbers? you can assume nothing else is going on on the rdb

Comment: I can obviously run a simulation....which would give me some numbers that answer the question, in empirical terms, I'm interested in in theory terms whats going on, if its always going to be effectively serialised then I wont bother